# How to fix dircolors in terminal?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, themes, gnome-terminal

Im running 16.04lts, and tried to install the solorized theme to my terminal. In doing so I somehow must've replaced my dircolors as they no longer work and typing `ls` has all the text the same color. This makes reading code errors very difficult to read. I followed this [guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/solarized-must-have-color-paletter-for.html) to install the theme but now all text is same color in terminal. How can I fix dircolors?

Comment: which of the script did you run there?

Comment: That article is from 2011, whereas your distro is from 2016. Somewhere in between gnome-terminal started to ship the Solarized color scheme out of the box. There's nothing to install, you should've just selected it in the profile preferences. As for your current problem: Just undo the steps you did that touch `~/.dircolors` and similar files.

Comment: @egmont Im not exactly sure how to undo what i did.